# Scriptaculous not working with the latest Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

This is a really weird problem that I have been having. When I download *Scriptaculous* from the official web site, [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us), bundled in the ZIP is *prototype.js* version 1.6.0.1. This works perfectly fine, I can follow along the wiki examples and begin learning. However, when I upgrade to prototype 1.6.0.2 (the latest version) from [prototypejs.org](http://www.prototypejs.org/)  everything breaks. I have read the documentation, named the new file *prototype.js* and nothing works. Any help is greatly appreciated!
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scriptaculous is a JS library built on top of prototype. As such, they will be behind prototype in their release schedule. To ensure that scriptaculous works only use it with the prototype file that came in the download.

Sure, given enough time and energy, you can find all the changed references from prototype 1.6.0.1 to 1.6.0.2 but is there really something in the newer version of prototype that you need today?  If not, then just wait for the scripaculous to update.

Comment: This is true, however, the documentation for scriptaculous sayd you can use version 1.6.0.1 or later. Really it's no problem, it's just the fact that, that's what I read.

Comment: "Or later" has, silently, "as far as we know".  They can't possibly predict things in the future that will break the library.

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest script.aculo.us version driectly from their source code repository. The zipped version provided on their website is ancient. I'm running the latest script.aculo.us taken from their repo last week with the latest Prototype (1.6.0.3) without a glitch.